# How to prevent Macbook from bluetooth reconnecting to lost connections?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth

I have an Macbook Pro mid-2017 and a pair of Bluetooth ear-buds.

When I turn bluetooth off and on again on the Macbook, the ear-buds do not reconnect automatically, but when I just put the ear-buds in its case, so they turn off and I take them out again, they reconnect automatically.

When I get home and take the ear-buds out they still do reconnect, but when I take them out on the next morning, they don't.

It seems like there is an timeout or something for "lost Bluetooth connections".

I already tried this command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist DontPageAudioDevices 1
```

Like I described it works, when I turn Bluetooth off and on again, but not when I only turn the ear-buds off.

Answer (score 0):

For now I did an workaround with Controlplane:
[Run program if connected to specific wifi?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139267/run-program-if-connected-to-specific-wifi)

When I leave work and my Mac does not detect the wifi it will turn off bluetooth.